# Application for carte de séjour

Tags: france, citizenship

Our "handholding" lady was supposed to apply for our *carte de séjour* for us but we have heard nothing, is it possible to check if we are in the system and, if so, how do I do it? We have tried to contact her regarding this, but to no avail.

Comment: What is the basis of your _carte de séjour_?  How was the "handholding lady" engaged, and by whom?  What is the scope of her duties?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume it hasn't been done. There is no easy way to check but, with very few exceptions (*compétences et talents* permits mostly), applying for a *carte de séjour* requires being physically present at the *préfecture* (it cannot be done by mail nor through a representative or lawyer).

You haven't told us what kind of status you were hoping for and who this “handholding” lady was but the whole setup seems sketchy to me, she might have misled you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something about this **right away** as the clock is ticking down.

Please read [this reference](https://www.francerights.org/applying-for-your-new-cds.html) from France Rights.

The procedure for applying for a WARP (Withdrawal Agreement Residence Permit) is extremely straightforward and not in any way onerous.

You will need to explain why your application is late but right now it is still doable. Don't delay any further. There is a list of organisations that can provide practical and timely help with the process without charge.

[This Reference](https://www.remaininfrance.fr/werecommend) lists the organisations which can help with the application.

Comment: "There is a list of organisations that can provide practical and timely help" could you please list out a few of them? I have similar issue and not aware what can be done.

Comment: @user22132 I've amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: This answer seems to assume that the OP is a **British citizen**, since the *Withdrawal Agreement Residence Permit* only applies to them. It is, however, not clear that this is the case.

Comment: @user22132 Thank you. Its really worth checking.